# Android gradle Upload NDK symbols on every build

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-ndk, crashlytics

I want to upload NDK symbols on every build i do,

Under my Android inside gradle i use to have:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def variantName = variant.name.capitalize()
    println("symbols will be added on varinat ${variantName}")
    def task = project.task("ndkBuild${variantName}")
    task.finalizedBy project.("uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFile${variantName}")
}
```

1. this does not compile anymore since i moved to FireBase  :

   **Could not get unknown property 'uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFile**
2. I don't see this task running.
3. I basiclly need this task to run on every build:

   > ./gradlew app:assembleBUILD_VARIANT\
   >              app:uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFileBUILD_VARIANT

Comment: Are you including the buildtype as well? If you look at the list of gradle tasks, that jobs is generated for every flavor and build type

Answer (score 4):

Add this at the bottom of app's `build.gradle` outside `android { ... }` block.

```
afterEvaluate {
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def variantName = variant.name.capitalize()
        println("symbols will be added on variant ${variantName}")

        def task = tasks.findByName("assemble${variantName}")
        def uploader = "uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFile${variantName}"

        // This triggers after task completion
        task?.finalizedBy(uploader)

        // This ensures ordering
        task?.mustRunAfter(uploader)
    }
}
```

You can try without `afterEvaluate` block. It should still work.

Answer (score 2):

Likely you'd need to use Firebase App Distribution, which permits automatic upload of release build artifacts - and if you have the artifact with the matching debug symbols, they could actually  be used - without the matching assembly, the symbols are somewhat irrelevant.

Number 1 is obviously a wrongful assumption, because the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/ndk-reports) clearly states:

```
./gradlew app:assembleBUILD_VARIANT app:uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFileBUILD_VARIANT
```

And this is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59160557/firebase-crashlytics-android-ndk-empty-symbols-on-crash-reports).

---

In order to always upload, one can create a task dependency:

```
assembleRelease.finalizedBy uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFileRelease
```

This may require setting `unstrippedNativeLibsDir` and `strippedNativeLibsDir`.